# Cannot boot from Ubuntu 14.04 live usb

Tags: boot, usb

I recently downloaded and created Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit using Unebootin. The process was successful,but after reboot the screen is stuck with Syslinux screen forever. I tried numerous times,but everything ended in vain. Any help folks !!.

Comment: Try with usb-creator-gtk

Comment: Try also [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: Make sure your usb stick is formatted with a FAT32 file system.

Comment: you can also create live usb using rufus if you have windows

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine using an EFI BIOS?

If so, you'll want to make sure that you created your image using a program that can write a EFI bootable image.  unetbootin is not one of these programs.

You can do this via terminal in Ubuntu by typing

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/home/user/path/to/iso.iso
```

Make sure to change /dev/sdb1 to the location of your thumb drive/cd media.